# Какой сервер выбрать (т.е. ПО)?

Tags: веб-сервер, поиск-программ

Хочу без хостинга прикрутить к сайту (уже давно опубликованному) одну систему, которая работает пока на Denwer или Open Server.
Система полностью независима от сайта (файловой системой сайта и БД), она крутится на другом сервере.

Почитал рекомендации разрабов Denwer'a и OpenServer'a, они **НАСТОЯТЕЛЬНО НЕ РЕКОМЕНДУЮТ** своё ПО для выхода с ним на внешку, максимум для локалки.

Так какое ПО порекомендуют те, кто уже делал такую махинацию?

Comment: Хотите полную копию прод-окружения - поднимайте виртуалку, ставьте тот же апач/нгинкс там.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Купить хостинг с выделенным ip и запускать систему на нем с доступом по ip-адресу. В зависимости от сложности системы может подойти даже shared hosting.

---

Ой, вам же без хостинга надо. Ну тогда организовать связку необходимого ПО (Apache, MyQSL, PHP) на локальной машине, организовать DynDNS или купить выделенный IP и предоставлять данные с нее. Можно выделить отдельную машину, запустить на ней WAMP и расшарить доступ из сети. Я не думаю, что кому-то может понадобиться взламывать вас.

---

> Сайт одного из крупнейшего университета Сибири, не вздумается ломать каким-нибудь недо-хакерам, завалившим сессию или точащим зуб на деканат ВУЗа? Сомневаюсь... Да и если что-то случиться с центральным сайтам или с серверами. Меня расстреляют при попытке выброситься из окна.

Хмм. В этом случае попытки взлома более, чем вероятны. Вашему сайту, думаю, придется протестировать на себе большую часть эксплойтов, появляющихся в сети. В этом случае я бы перенес сайт на какой-то российский хостинг с делегированием обязанностей по слежению за его работоспособностью, делал бы ежедневные бекапы и не добавлял на сайт сомнительные сервисы.

Если у вас есть хороший опыт в настройке apache, то ничто не мешает установить его на отдельную машину и вывести в сеть, минуя различные опасности готовых сборок.